# How to get only all facebook profil pictures with access token and 'user_photos' permission?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

How to get only ALL facebook profil pictures with access token and 'user_photos' permission?

I dont need other albums or other uploaded images, only the profile pictures. I have an access token, which inlcudes 'user_photos' permission.

That URL returns ALL uploaded images:
https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos/uploaded?access_token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX

Comment: Then you’ll have to go through the user’s albums first and find the one named “Profile Pictures”.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this in FQL, this is fairly easy:

```
select pid, object_id, src from photo where album_object_id in (select object_id from album where name = 'Profile Pictures' and owner = me()) order by position
```

Keep in mind that FQL will be deprecated on 30th April, 2015.

To do this via Graph API, you need to take three steps:

1. Get list of albums (see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/albums/)

   `/me/albums`
2. Parse the result in your application and look for the album name "Profile Pictures"
3. Request all photos in the "Profile Pictures" album (see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/album/photos)

   `/{album_id}/photos`